# onchange and onclick event handlers executing in response to onchange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

My goal is to manipulate data entered into a text field after a button is pressed. This is done by collecting the data using the onchange property of a text input element, and then manipulating the data after the onclick event is triggered.

However, both handlers execute in response to the onchange event, while nothing happens in response to onclick event.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {input: undefined}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" marginTop="200px">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Timestamp Microservice</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Converts a Unix timestamp (2365145258) to a natural language date (December 16, 2016) and vice versa.
        </p>
        <form>    
          <input type="text" onChange={(event) => this.setState({input: event.target.value})}/> <br/>
          <input type="submit" onClick={() => console.log(this.state.input)}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have to wrap `console.log` in a function in `onClick` for the `submit` button? i.e. `onClick={() => console.log(this.state.input)}`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me lol. But after fixing it the same problem still arises.

Comment: Your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/swapnil95/k0jpruyu/2/

Comment: Can you explain why it works in jsfiddle but not in my case?